# View search Result in a new Activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search form on a fragment which works perfectly. At the moment I have a `RecyclerView` at the bottom of the form but I want it to load the search result on a new activity. Please help

**layout.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ranake.rana.Search">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_outline2"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_make"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Make"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#7f8c8d"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/className"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/input_outline2"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_model"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Model"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#7f8c8d"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_red_border"
                    android:text="Clear"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/result_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




</LinearLayout>
```

**Search.java**:

```
public class Search extends Fragment {

    private EditText mSearchField;
    private Button mSearchBtn;

    private RecyclerView mResultList;

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);


        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cars");


        mSearchField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

        mResultList = (RecyclerView)  view.findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();

                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

            }
        });




        return view;
    }

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cars, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cars, UsersViewHolder>(

                Cars.class,
                R.layout.list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Cars model, int position) {


                viewHolder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDesc(), model.getImage(), model.getMileage(), model.getTrans(), model.getFuel(), model.getPrice(), model.getLocation());

            }
        };

        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    // View Holder Class

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userTitle, String userDesc, String userImage, String userMileage, String userTrans, String userFuel, String userPrice, String userLocation){

            TextView user_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            TextView user_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            TextView user_mileage = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_mileage);
            TextView user_trans = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_trans);
            TextView user_fuel = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_fuel);
            TextView user_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_price);
            TextView user_location = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_location);


            user_title.setText(userTitle);
            user_desc.setText(userDesc);

            user_mileage.setText(userMileage);
            user_trans.setText(userTrans);
            user_fuel.setText(userFuel);
            user_price.setText(userPrice);
            user_location.setText(userLocation);

            Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


        }




    }
```

When the search Button is clicked, I want it to open the new activity and load the results there.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this `searchText` to the next Activity (I'm calling it ResultsActivity) by passing it as an extra on the Intent:

```
private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("searchText",searchText);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then receive it on the other Activity using [Intent.getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()):

```
String searchText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("searchText");
```

And finally populate the RecyclerView from that Activity:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cars, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cars, UsersViewHolder>(

        Cars.class,
        R.layout.list_layout,
        UsersViewHolder.class,
        firebaseSearchQuery

) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Cars model, int position) {


        viewHolder.setDetails(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDesc(), model.getImage(), model.getMileage(), model.getTrans(), model.getFuel(), model.getPrice(), model.getLocation());

    }
};

mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```